# Is it possible to load 1 process to 2 contiguously partitions in memory?

Tags: memory-management, operating-system

I have a problem about management memory(OS).
Contiguous Memory Allocation is a technique that as far as i know it load a process in memory where has space contiguous.But i have doubt that whether I can load a process in 2 contiguously partitions in memory?
Suppose:

```
----------------
|process 1(3MB) |  partition 1
|-------------- |
|process 2 (4MB)|  partition 2
|---------------|
|process 3(2MB) |  partition 3
|---------------|
|process 1(1MB) |  partition 4

----------------
```

suppose in above example- process 1(3MB) and process 3(2MB) completed their execution. Hence two spaces are left i.e. 3MB and 2MB. Let’s suppose process 5 of size 5MB comes. The empty space in memory cannot be allocated as no spanning is allowed in contiguous allocation. The rule says that process must be contiguously present in main memory to get executed. Hence it results in External Fragmentation.

But I want to question to you guys is if process 1(3MB) and process 2(4MB) completed their execution and two spaces are left. Let’s suppose process 5 of size 7MB comes.Can empty space in memory in partion 1 and partiton 2 be allocated for process 5?

Comment: http://sweetnothingsaresosweet.blogspot.com/2011/02/dynamic-and-relocatable-dynamic.html?m=1

Comment: You can reference to here to know more about that

Comment: yeah thank you about that